# I don't understand these lines

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have these lines on a library, something is not working so I'm going deep into the module to figure it out.

```
on(event: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this;
on(event: 'close', listener: (hadError: boolean) => void): this;
on(event: 'connect', listener: () => void): this;
on(event: 'data', listener: (data: Buffer) => void): this;
on(event: 'drain', listener: () => void): this;
on(event: 'end', listener: () => void): this;
on(event: 'error', listener: (err: Error) => void): this;
on(event: 'lookup', listener: (err: Error, address: string, family: string | number, host: 
string) => void): this;
on(event: 'ready', listener: () => void): this;
on(event: 'timeout', listener: () => void): this;
```

I have a call to it from a line:

```
PLC.on("Get Instance Attribute List", async (err, data) => { }
```

But it does nothing, and the issue is actually that I don't understand the lines, why do I have many on() methods on the class?

Comment: Presumably that's a _TypeScript_ file, those are [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). There's only one _implementation_.

Comment: This looks like a type declaration. This `on` function is used to assign event listeners.